# Force PostgreSQL clients to use SSL on Amazon RDS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, ssl

I'm running a PostgreSQL 9.4.x instance on Amazon RDS.  I can successfully connect to that server using SSL using a command line similar to this one:

```
psql "host=x.y.z.rds.amazonaws.com dbname=aaa user=bbb sslmode=verify-full"
```

How can I *force* clients to use SSL (to make eavesdropping harder)?  The following should fail to connect:

```
psql "host=x.y.z.rds.amazonaws.com dbname=aaa user=bbb sslmode=disable"
```

As far as I can tell, on Amazon RDS you can't edit [`pg_hba.conf`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html), so I can't put `hostssl` entries in there.

[This AWS blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-rds-support-for-ssl-connections/) suggests how it could be done with MySQL, but I can't find links to similar information for PostgreSQL.

My motivation is to prevent myself (or other users) from accidentally transmitting sensitive information unencrypted across the network.

Comment: I can't tell for sure, but apparently there is no way to do that on RDS, as you can't edit pg_hba.conf as you stated yourself... :( ... I'd like to be proven wrong though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like this has finally been added. [From the docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_PostgreSQL.html#PostgreSQL.Concepts.General.SSL):

> You can use the rds.force_ssl parameter to force connections to your PostgreSQL database to use SSL. The default value is 0 (off). When you set this parameter to 1 (on) and restart your instance, your database will refuse any non-SSL connections. This parameter also sets the PostgreSQL parameter ssl to on as well as modifies your instance's pg_hba.conf to support this SSL configuration.